# Which of the following(s) is/are (a) preferred structure(s)?

Tags: sentence-construction

Among the followings, are there preferred sentences ?

[edited: the original sentence used a phrase "on the rise", which seemed to make the sentence less formal]

1. The incidence of diabetes and the incidence of heart disease have been steadily increasing in the last decade.
2. The incidences of diabetes and heart disease have been steadily increasing in the last decade.
3. The incidence of diabetes and that of heart disease have been steadily increasing in the last decade.
4. others
5. If there are three subjects, for example, (a) the incidence of diabetes, (b) the incidence of heart disease, (c) the incidence of high blood pressure, is there a "preferred" way to construct a sentence?

Comment: This is an editing question and that is not allowed here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could drop "incidence" entirely in informal writing, and the phrase "on the rise" makes it informal.
Definitely, with three items, you could say

> Heart disease, high blood pressure and diabetes are on the rise.